# 360 video glitch on Oculus Go APK

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusgo

I have published the same Unity 360 video app to Gear VR and it works perfectly and used to on Oculus Go. However, recently this glitch has appeared when loading a new scene or playing a video file via VideoPlayer on the Oculus Go. Does anyone know a way of removing this or even what it is? It doesn't appear in  the Unity editor and seems localised to the Oculus Go.

[image]